# Open files from list (or other object) in Python IF they exist

Tags: python, file, load

Let's say I have a biiig garden, and I'm a total flower nerd, and I keep a monthly folder of csv files where I keep track of the different kinds of flowers I have and their numbers in individual files. Not every flower blooms every month, so if I were to make a list of all the flower files I have, it might look like this:

```
['Roses','Lilies','Tulips','Cornflowers','Sunflowers','Hydrangea','Daisies','Dahlias','Primroses','Hibiscus']
```

etc. (with **many more** actual files in there), but the folder for March might look like this:

```
['Tulips','Primroses']
```

while the folder for June might look like this:

```
['Roses','Primroses','Daisies','Dahlias','Hibiscus']
```

Now, I run the same analyses over these files every month, because I want to see how my flowers grew, which different colours I have, etc. But I don't want to have to redo the whole file opening block every month to fit the subset of flower files I have in my specific folder - especially because I have 30+ files.

So, is there a simple, effective way to tell Python "look, this is the pool of file names I would want to load data from, pick what's there in the folder and load it" without having it create any files that aren't there and without having to write 30+ load statements?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: what have you written so far? Why not just get the contents of the directory and run your analysis on all the files in that directory (possibly that match certain criteria)?

Comment: I realise this is a made-up example but to be honest it sounds like a job for a database, rather than a bunch of files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman perhaps the files have to be parsed and the data put into a database

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm getting this data as a .zip file with about 30 subfolders, in which I have lots of very different files that don't have any similarities in terms of field names etc. and very messy data, so I'm loading them into Python to clean them up and analyse them. If there's a simple way to aggregate all of those in SQL (or wherever) even though they're not similar at all, I'm happy to try! :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to approach this would be to list the contents of your monthly directory using `os.listdir(directory)` and check whether the flower names are in your list of acceptable names:

```
import os
path = '/path/to/the/flower/directory'
flowers = ['Roses','Lilies','Tulips','Cornflowers','Sunflowers','Hydrangea','Daisies','Dahlias','Primroses','Hibiscus']

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file in flowers: # if the file name is in `flowers`
       with open(path + file, 'r') as flower_file:
       # do your analysis on the contents
```

The file name would need to match the string in `flowers` exactly, though. I would guess it is more likely that the file name is something like `hydrangea.csv`, so you might want to do some extra filtering, e.g.

```
flowers = ['roses','lilies','tulips','cornflowers']

for file in os.listdir(path):
    # file has extension .csv and the file name minus the last 4 chars is in `flowers`
    if file.endswith(".csv") and file[0:-4] in flowers:
        with open(path + file, 'r') as flower_file:
        # do your analysis on the contents
```

If you have your flower folders organised by date (or any other grouping), e.g. like this:

```
/home/flower_data/
                  2018-04/
                  2018-05/
                  2018-06/
```

you could do something like this from your top level `path` directory:

```
path = '/home/flower_data'
# for every item in the directory
for subf in os.scandir(path):
    # if the item is a directory
    if subf.is_dir():
        # for every file in path/subfolder
        for file in os.listdir( subf.path ):
            if file.endswith('.csv') and file[0:-4] in flowers: 
               # print out the full path to the file and the file name 
               fullname = os.path.join(subf.path, file)
               print('Now looking at ' + fullname)
               with open(fullname, 'r') as flower_file:
                   # analyse away!
```

Comment: Hey, this looks great, thank you so much! Do you know if it's possible to include a statement that also goes into every subfolder for each month? I just noticed that I happen to have all the "monthly" data in subfolders and I'll get them like that every time, so it'd be a ton of work to extract all the files from the subfolders and figure out where they belong..

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick - thanks! :)

Comment: Hey, I'd love to :) but, right now I'm still getting this error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" and then the filepath, but without the subfolder. :( Any ideas what I might have done wrong? https://imgur.com/a/Hd1uNQr

Comment: I've added a `print` statement to demonstrate the full path to the file. Not sure if that's where your problem is?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8bygbUO that seems to work, although the last slash is a backslash, I don't know if that's a problem? But that'd mean that the issue lies in the last part "with open(path + file, 'r') as flower_file:". I hate that I'm so bad at this, I'm just trying to figure stuff out :(

Comment: It is difficult when you are first learning this stuff! `os.path.join(subf.path, file)` joins the path to the file with the file name, so you can substitute that into the `open` statement: `with open(os.path.join(subf.path, file), 'r') as flower_file:`

Comment: Oh thank you, that works now! Is there a way I can assign every opened file to an object so I can use it for the analysis? All of the files are vastly different, so I can't use the same operations on all of them.

Comment: I tried assigning every file to its file name in the for loop, but it gives me this error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`